# Looking for .NET library to create PDF

Tags: .net, pdf, pdf-generation

We are looking for a .NET PDF creator. It needs to be .NET, so we can just copy the file(s) onto the server, not having to install anything.

We only need to create a PDF with some text and images and a heading, that's all.

Anyone know a good one? We are happy to buy if there is a good one that is easy to use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've been using [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) with some success, but I haven't worked with it directly.

We've used it with images and text, it's free to use, and doesn't seem to require anything beyond the iTextSharp dll. License is [Affero GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html)

Comment: I tried iTextSharp because it seems to be the most popular, and it worked. I haven't had a chance to try the others, but thanks everyone for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I have used iTextSharp and PDFSharp (http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php). PDFSharp handles images better.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [FO.NET](http://fonet.codeplex.com/Wikipage) before and have been very happy with the degree of control I have over the PDF output.  If the source data for your document is XML (or can easily be exported as XML), simply define an XSLT to transform the XML to [XSL-FO](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/default.asp) and run it through FO.NET.

What's nice about this approach is the XSLT serves as the template for your PDF (instead of creating document elements in code).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) to good effect, but its not trivial to write code to generate pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is feasible for you, but we use Business Objects, and it exports to a number of formats. The SDK lets you run a report on the fly and save it as PDF without much trouble.

If you've got access to an enterprise reporting system, that's another way to go.

Answer (score 0):

PdfLib - http://www.pdflib.com/  - very fast - not free