# How to Export contents in a list box to pdf?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

in my application i have  to Export the contents in a list box to .pdf after clicking the export button which i would have it in my application ... thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a .net pdf library to do this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619788/looking-for-net-library-to-create-pdf) is a related SO question.